# How do you set the width of the background image for this Javascript code?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

The [freezegframe.js](http://freezeframe.chrisantonellis.com/) plugin by Chris Antonellis allows you to basically start an animated gif on a mouseover. It has some nice things like fading in the animation as well. This is the required syntax to kick in the plugin: you set

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="freezeframe.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
freezeframe = new FreezeFrame();
</script>
```

in your header file, and then simply:

```
<img src="img/mr_div_retro_sphere.gif" freezeframe />
```

within your HTML body. The image can then be styled with

```
figure.freezeframe-container {
    border-radius: 3px;
    border-top: 1px solid __border__;
    border-left: 1px solid __border__;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    -moz-box-shadow: 5px 5px 3px #888;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 5px 5px 3px #888;
    box-shadow: 5px 5px 3px #888;
}
```

As indicated in the documentation (see original link). The problem is that there is currently no way to style the background image. See the test example [here](http://www.theshapeofmath.com/playground).

As you can see from the test, the background image is sized using the original gif. However, because I want the site to be elastic in sizing, then I need for a way to size the initial image.

I've contacted the author, but he explains that the difficulty is that the code currently takes the first frame of the image---it seems unclear how to attach a CSS styling command to it.

Comment: you can use css3 `background-size:100%;` otherwise you could add the image as an `<img />` position fixed and the content on top positioned absolute with a higher z-index.  That way you can just resize the image

Comment: @peter: you mean background-size:100% within the freezeframe-container CSS? I have done that on the test site but there is no difference. As for your other suggestion, I think this would involve writing a script to change the z-index when the movie is played, no? Is there a way to modify the JS code to include a styling command for the background and not try and replace it? After all, the point of the JS script is to make things pretty (change the opacity of the background to bring in/out the video).

Comment: I think it would be background:100% on the .freezeframe-container

Comment: @peter: Unfortunately, that doesn't work either (see below comment to @gatebasher_311).

Answer (score 0):

That's weird, but a hacky way to make it look decent would be this:

```
.freezeframe-container { background-repeat: no-repeat; background-size: 78%; }
```

But it looks like the initial background image doesn't match the animated gif too well.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Unfortunately, that doesn't work. I believe the background element is not actually the fixed (first frame) of the gif that you see. The background element is a grey loading screen. The command you suggested has no effect on the first static frame that the viewer sees.

Comment: I was able to make it work in my inspector, and that's how I came to those values. Your CSS selector may have to be more weighted (or inline).

Comment: Strange. What browser are you testing in? Your command seems to work (though the background-repeat has no effect for me) in Safari, but not in Firefox or Chrome. I'm not a huge fan of this hack because it requires you to specify the sizing for each individual background. Hmmm.

Comment: I am using FireBug in Firefox and I just input the rules inline on the .freezeframe-container element. Make sure to delete the background rules that are already in place ie: I believe that background-repeat is set to repeat initially.